# Would Newton's law in the solar system be independent from a presumed different fundamental gravitational law?

Tags: general-relativity, newtonian-gravity, black-holes, solar-system, post-newtonian

A thought experiment:

Let's assume the gravitational field of a black hole without any neighbors would be stronger than the Schwarzschild metric in the Newtonian limit.

Now, we let a solar system (sun and planets, much smaller mass than the black hole) orbit around this black hole at $r>> R_s$, so that the tidal forces are nearly zero.

My question is, although the fundamental gravity law is "set" to be stronger, would the planets around the sun experience **Newton's law**?

The metric in the solar system can be calculated with the static, sperically symmetric solution of the field equations, namely
$ds^2=-Bdt^2+Adr^2+\text{angular terms}$ using the Newtonian limit (asymptotically flat spacetime), lim A(r) = 1, because due to the free fall (orbit) around the black hole, there are no forces, no curvature experienced by the solar system as it is moving *along* the curvature in free fall.
That would presumably lead to the derivation of the Schwarzschild metric.

The question therefore is, whether this solar system does experience an asymptotically flat space because of the free fall around the BH and is this asymptotically flatness of space **independent from the underlying gravity law of the black hole**?

Remark: **Tidal forces** are theoretically possible inside this solar system, because for example a planet experiences another force of gravity if it is behind the sun (in greater distance) in relation to the central black hole, than if it is in front of the sun (in nearer distance) in relation to the black hole. However, these tidal forces are very small at galactic distances (see for example [Are there tidal forces between the solar system and the galactic centre?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/702248/are-there-tidal-forces-between-the-solar-system-and-the-galactic-centre)), even if the gravitational field produced by the black hole were stronger. The *difference* measured within the solar system between "black hole gravity is *stronger* than Newtonian" and "black hole gravity is Newtonian" is even much smaller.

This is just a thought experiment. It comes from the idea whether it is possible to create an alternative model of gravity by abandoning the weak field assumption.

Comment: What about tidal effects from the BH?

Comment: I think this answer really comes down to "what do you mean by 'stronger'"?  Also, I haven't seen a strict proof of this, but generally, "asymptotic flatness just comes from the fact that you have a localized matter distribution, so if you zoom out on the spacetime, then the matter distribution functionally becomes a point mass, and so the radiation and monopole terms dominate the far-away field.

Answer (score 1):

No. A system of nontrivial size in a gravitational field experiences tidal effects.

Acceleration due to gravity from an object of mass M is

$a(r) = \frac{GM}{r^2\sqrt{1-\frac{R_s}{r}}}$

where $R_s = \frac{2GM}{c^2}$

For $r \gg R_s$ this simplifies to the Newtonian form,

$a(r) = \frac{GM}{r^2}$

The solar system will be affected tidally by the distant black hole (although there's nothing special about it being a black hole - it could be a star,  etc).

$\Delta \vec a = \frac{GM}{r_1^2}\hat r_1 - \frac{GM}{r_2^2} \hat r_2$

where $r_1$ is the displacement from the black hole to the sun and $r_2$ is the displacement from the black hole to the planet, and $\Delta \vec a$ is the difference in the acceleration of the star and the planet towards the black hole, neglecting the acceleration of the planet with respect to the sun.

For $r_1 \gg |r_1-r_2|$

$\Delta \vec a \approx \frac{GM \Delta r}{r^3} \hat r$

This happens in the Solar system already all the time, e.g. the moon-earth system is affected by the Sun, the Sun-Earth system is affected by Jupiter, and so on.